# using function malloc() and free(), problems with initialized pointer

Tags: c, malloc, free, calloc

I'm not that new to coding but I faced a problem I couldn't explain to myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char    *test;

    test = (char *)calloc(15, sizeof(char));
    // test = "Wurstbrot";
    free(test);
}
```

If I compile this, `test` gets malloced and directly freed (what I expected).
But if I uncomment the comment, I get this error while compiling:

```
a.out(28953,0x104403dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10365cfae: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(28953,0x104403dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

When I remove the `free` function, it will work again.

My question now: why is it a problem here to free an initialized pointer?

Comment: In C you cannot copy a string with `=` (except in an initialisation). Please use `strcpy`. You are overwriting the pointer obtained from `calloc` with the pointer to a string literal, which cannot be passed to `free` because it was not obtained from `calloc` or `malloc`. Meanwhile, the pointer value obtained from the call to `calloc` is lost, and cannot be freed (is dangling).

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you but can you explain your last sentences, what do you mean with "is lost"

Comment: You obtained a pointer from `calloc` and then replaced the pointer with a different one, so the original value is lost. That means it is impossible to `free` the memory that you allocated, because you no longer know the pointer value. 'Lost' in the same sense that if you change a phone number in your contacts list, the previous number is lost. You no longer have it.

Answer (score 2):

`free` must be passed a null pointer or a valid pointer to a block allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `strdup()` or another heap allocation function.

If you uncomment `test = "Wurstbrot";` the pointer will point to static data, the string literal `"Wurstbrot"`. Passing this address to `free()` has undefined behavior.

Passing `test` uninitialized would have undefined behavior too. If you are lucky, this uninitialized variable might happen to contain a null pointer, thus not causing a problem with `free()`... Undefined behavior is undefined, anything may happen including no visible side effect. A runtime error such as the one reported by the C library is actually quite useful to find bugs. no side effect is probably no luck in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

When we analyze program run step by step:

**A)** Initialization before program starts running:
A memory space on the stack is allocated and the string "Wurstbrot" + '\0' is laid on that memory space. Say, that memory allocated for string starts at `AAAA:0000`; i.e. stack memory state is sth like below;

```
address     value
AAAA:0000   W
AAAA:0001   u
AAAA:0002   r
...
AAAA:0007   o
AAAA:0008   t
AAAA:0009   0 // that's a zero
```

**B)** When program starts running:

**Line 1**: A pointer variable is created. This variable sits on stack and is uninitialized. For a 32 bits system, this variable sits on the stack (say, at address `AAAA:0020` to `AAAA:0023` and contain some garbage value like `DBAC:5782` that points to some random memory.

```
address     value
AAAA:0020   DB
AAAA:0021   AC
AAAA:0022   57
AAAA:0023   82
```

**Line 2**:
Operating system allocates a memory space (probably on the heap) with a length of 15 bytes and hands the starting value to the program (say it starts from `DDDD:0000`). This value is assigned to your pointer variable and the pointer value on line 1 changes to `DDDD:0000`.

```
address     value
AAAA:0020   DD
AAAA:0021   DD
AAAA:0022   00
AAAA:0023   00
```

**Line 3**: `test = "Wurstbrot";` line resets the value of the pointer to point to the memory that was allocated at step (A). From now on, your pointer variable `test` do not point to the allocated memory space on the heap but the initialized memory space on the stack.

```
address     value
AAAA:0020   AA
AAAA:0021   AA
AAAA:0022   00
AAAA:0023   00
```

**Line 4**: This line, of course, raise error. It tries to free the initialized memory space at step (A), not the memory space that was allocated at step (B)/1.

**Solution**:

Line 3 should read as: `strcpy(test, "Wurstbrot");`